# concat two dataframe using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

We have one dataframe like

```
-0.140447131    0.124802527 0.140780106
0.062166349    -0.121484447 -0.140675515
-0.002989106    0.13984927  0.004382326
```

and the other as

```
1
1
2
```

We need to concat both the dataframe like

```
-0.140447131    0.124802527 0.140780106  1
0.062166349    -0.121484447 -0.140675515 1
-0.002989106    0.13984927  0.004382326  2
```

Comment: Both dataframes have common index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your first dataframe is like

```
In [281]: df1
Out[281]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.140447  0.124803  0.140780
1  0.062166 -0.121484 -0.140676
2 -0.002989  0.139849  0.004382
```

And, the second like,

```
In [283]: df2
Out[283]:
   d
0  1
1  1
2  2
```

Then you could create new column for `df1` using `df2`

```
In [284]: df1['d_new'] = df2['d']

In [285]: df1
Out[285]:
          a         b         c  d_new
0 -0.140447  0.124803  0.140780      1
1  0.062166 -0.121484 -0.140676      1
2 -0.002989  0.139849  0.004382      2
```

*The assumption however being both dataframes have common index*

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.concat and specify the axis equal to 1 (rows):

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

>>> df_new
          0         1         2  0
0 -0.140447  0.124803  0.140780  1
1  0.062166 -0.121484 -0.140676  2
2 -0.002989  0.139849  0.004382  3
```

Comment: If the index is not common then this will stack the rows, you'd need to pass `ignore_index=True`